# How to add ASPNET account on server 2008?

Tags: asp.net

i have an error like this:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with `CLSID
>   {65EB3876-89FF-459F-BF24-02E8DD7F2DB2}` failed due to the following
>
> > error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT:
> >     0x80070005
> >     (E_ACCESSDENIED))

and the page says to do this :

> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add
>   the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and
>   check the boxes for the desired access.

And... the problem is there! I can't see ASPNET user.I tried reinstall framework 4.0 but ASPNET user not created on IIS 7.5 . What is the solution ?

Answer (score 5):

In IIS7, the default user is no longer ASPNET but NETWORK SERVICE.

See this previous question: https://serverfault.com/questions/83194/asp-net-user-account-permissions-in-iis-7-on-windows-2008-server

I guess the error you're getting is out of date.

Comment: +1 Nice answer but please refrain from lobbying for acceptance. This site is structured in a way that will reward good questions, good answers and proper voting and acceptance. Please be a little more patient. If you feel the need then prod the n00b OP with a common a few days later.

Comment: i done it,but still get this error.But i m not sure its cause of getting is out of date.

Comment: Try granting the "Users" group Read permission on C:\Windows\assembly and C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework and apply to all their sub folders. Restart IIS to see if this fixes the problem.